Зачем нужны привязки команд в WPF?
Насколько я знаю, к кнопке в WPF можно привязать событие. Это событие позже исполняет какую-то логику. А зачем оно вообще нужно? Почему нельзя просто заиметь функцию, поместить туда эту логику, и прикреплять к каждой кнопке Click="{эта функция}"? И к чему еще можно привязать команды, помимо кликабельных элеметов?

И сколько будет весить ваше приложение с кодом в кликах? 100 килобайт? Несолидно! А у конкурентов с командами - 100 мегабайт! Круто же! Сразу ощущается мощь! / А что вы в резюме напишете: C#, WPF и всё? А другие разрабы впишут дополнительно "паттерны", "команды" и другие умные пустые слова... И кого возьмут на работу? То-то!

Тут все довольно просто. Когда ваш проект становиться больше "Привет мир" и "Калькулятора", вы начнете думать о том, как оптимизировать код, как сократить код, как избавиться от дубликатов, как абстрагироваться от UI, и т.д., вот тут приходят на помощь "привязки", которые позволяют писать код так, будто это библиотека, храня данные как и положено, в классах и свойствах, а не в UI. Когда ваш проект станет еще больше, и над ним будет трудиться группа людей, где часть отвечает за код, а часть за UI, то там и вовсе критично писать все "абстракциями", чтоб одна команда не ждала другую.
